# Filtering on a subform on navigation control

Tags: mysql, ms-access, xampp, ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert a filter on a form I have placed in the navigation control.  What I am trying to achieve is I am using a macro on pressing the 'Find Client' button and the form should filter to that client.

Firstly I am getting this error (see diagram error set 1).
[image]

Secondly the filter is not working, it works on the form when not in navigation control (changed it though as per convention for navigation control).  Getting this error (See Diagram error set 2)
[image]

Lastly when all done I am getting this erro (See Diagram error set 3)
[image]

I know it could be a silly error.  Also I have used macro builder instead of VBA.  This is what the ApplyFilter macro looks like (Diagram 4)
[image]

The backend is XAMPP and is connected using Access ODBC as frontend.

Comment: Cannot reference a subform (either normal or Navigation) same as when the form is opened as standalone form. Referencing a normal subform container object requires referencing through the subform container. Referencing a Navigation form object is even trickier. I NEVER use Navigation form. Is your main form actually named Main_Navigation_Form?

Comment: Yes my main form is actually named Main_Navigation_Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ApplyFilter macro is expecting **"name of control that corresponds to the subform or subreport to be filtered"**. Not able to get navigation form to work and tried numerous combinations of referencing. Possibly this macro will only work with a normal form/subform arrangement. I can get VBA to work:

```
Private Sub Textbox_Find_ClientName_AfterUpdate()
Forms!Main_Navigation_Form.NavigationSubform.Form.Filter = "EntityName Like '*" & Forms!Main_Navigation_Form.NavigationSubform.Form.Textbox_Find_ClientName & "*'"
Forms!Main_Navigation_Form.NavigationSubform.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```